# How can I back to before 2 screen Android?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

This is the scenario: I've got 3 pages; the first page A is the main page and uses splash, the second page is the B page, the third page is the C page. I want to navigate from C to A but I do not want to see the splash. I don't want to see splash but when I open page A splash always comes. I don't want to delete splash.

I try some code e.g. :

1-*Intent goScreen = new Intent(C.this or this@C, A.class);
goScreen.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(gotoScreenVar);*

2-*val intent = Intent(this@A, C::class.java)
startActivity(intent)* ...

Answer (score 0):

Create this extension property:

```
val Activity.isLaunchedFromHomeScreen: Boolean
    get() = intent?.let {
        it.action == Intent.ACTION_MAIN &&
                it.categories.orEmpty().contains(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER)
    } ?: false
```

Then in Activity A, you can check this Boolean to decide whether to show the splash.

But I caution you about creating a splash screen this way. Now that Android 12 has built-in splash screens, your app is going to show two splash screens on Android 12 and higher. You might want to use the [splash screen library](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreen) to create one that works consistently across all versions of Android. Or create another property to decide to show your implementation only on versions lower than Android 11:

```
val shouldShowSplashScreen: Boolean 
    get() = isLaunchedFromHomeScreen && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R
```

Answer (score 0):

While navigating from Activity C to Activity A, you can pass some data to the intent.
Like

```
intent.putBoolean("shouldHideSplash", true);
```

and on Activity A, you can check if intent has **shouldHideSplash**, you can skip the splash and can do whatever you want.